# How to write specializations of a method of a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, specialization

I'm writing a template class for a dynamic list that allows you to insert three different types of data. I want to create three methods to insert an item within the list using the specializations. What is the right way to do this?

```
template <class T, class U, class V> class list 
{

.....

}

template <> list <class T> :: add (T item) {
   ...
   // insert elem type T
   ...
}

template <> list <class U> :: add (U item) {
   ...
   // insert elem type U
   ...    
}

template <> list <class V> :: add (V item) {
   ...
   // insert elem type V
   ...    
}
```

Comment: Don't specialize; *overload*.

Comment: This is very far from anything compiling. Your first line is invalid already, I assume you meant `class list`? How are you planning on specializing a ternary template with just one type?

Comment: yes! it's class list!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specialise at all. Just define your `add` functions as

```
void add(T item) {}
void add(U item) {}
void add(V item) {}
```

(from within the class).

[Here's](http://codepad.org/nyJ8m5EK) a matching example.

Comment: You'll just need to be careful not to instantiate list with any two of T,U,V being the same type.